# How to find the angle between this vector and the x-axis?

Tags: vectors

**Question**:If $\vec{r}=3t\hat{i} + (4t-5t^2)\hat{j}$, find the angle between $\vec{r}$ and the x-axis?

**My attempt**: Let the angle between $\vec{r}$ and the x-axis be $\theta$

$\vec{r}.\hat{i}=r\cdot i\cdot \cos(\theta)$

$\vec{r}.\hat{i}=r_x \cdot i_x+r_y \cdot i_y$

Therefore, $r\cdot i \cdot \cos(\theta)=r_x\cdot i_x+r_y \cdot i_y$

$\cos(\theta)=\frac{r_x \cdot i_x+r_y \cdot i_y}{r \cdot i}$

$\cos(\theta)=\frac{r_x \cdot i_x}{r*i}$

$\cos(\theta)=\frac{r_x}{r}$

$\cos(\theta)=\frac{3t}{\sqrt{(3t)^2+(4t-5t^2)^2}}$

$\cos(\theta)=\frac{3t}{\sqrt{9t^2+16t^2+25t^4-40t^3}}$

$\cos(\theta)=\frac{3t}{\sqrt{25t^2+25t^4-40t^3}}$

$\cos(\theta)=\frac{3t}{\sqrt{5t^2(5+5t^2-8t)}}$

$\cos(\theta)=\frac{3t}{t\sqrt{5(5+5t^2-8t)}}$

$\cos(\theta)=\frac{3}{\sqrt{5(5+5t^2-8t)}}$

**My problem**: I am unable to simplify it further. Please help.

Comment: Wouldn't taking $\arccos$ of both sides solve for $\theta$?

Comment: $\theta=\tan^{-1} \frac{4-5t}{3}$, it will depend on $t$

Comment: The value $$t$$ will either be 0 or 1.6

Comment: @ADITYA, How did you get that?

Comment: Used your formula and equated it with $cos 53$ 's value...  The answer will always depend on the value of $$t$$ as yours it a family of vectors in 2D plane...

Answer (score 1):

As noted already, the angle $\theta$ satisfies $\displaystyle\tan \theta = \frac{4t-5t^2}{3t}=\frac{4-5t}{3}\,$, and therefore $\theta$ depends on $t\,$. Consider for example:

- $\displaystyle \;t=\frac{4}{5}\;$: $\displaystyle\;\;\;\;\vec{r}=\frac{12}{5}\hat{i} \;\;\implies\;\; \theta = 0$
- $\displaystyle \;t=\frac{1}{5}\;$: $\displaystyle\;\;\;\;\vec{r}=\frac{3}{5}\hat{i} + \frac{3}{5}\hat{j} \;\;\implies\;\; \theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

You did everything correctly, now to solve for the angle:
$$
\theta = \arccos \left( \frac{3}{\sqrt{5\left(5+5t^2-8t\right)}}\right)
$$

Comment: But isn't $t$ unknown?

Comment: @MrAP For each such value of $t$, you get a different point in the plane, and hence a different angle for $\theta$. You can only hope to produce $\theta$ as a function of $t$, which you did

Comment: But my teacher worked out a specific value for θ. 53 degrees i guess. I think he was wrong.

Comment: @MrAP then there is some extra information in the problem that you did not give

Comment: No. That is all information he gave. BTW, i did not understand his procedure and when i asked him he gave some vague explanation which i did not understand. He was saying that since the magnitude of the y component of $\vec{r}$ is the sum of two terms, one having degree 1 and another having degree 2, the y component will be initially straight and after that it will become parabolic and then he went to work out the problem on the board in a very clumpsy manner. I guess he is wrong.

Comment: @MrAP perhaps he is asking what will the angle look like for very large $t$? or very small $t$? For small $t$, you end up with $$\arccos(3/5) \approx 53.13^\circ$$